# Can you export an interface by itself in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I have this code

IDatabaseModel.ts

```
export interface IDatabaseModel {}
```

IDatabaseModels.ts

```
const IDatabaseModel = require('./IDatabaseModel');

export interface IDatabaseModels {
    currencies : IDatabaseModel;        
}
```

And when compiling I get the error

```
IDatabaseModels.ts: error TS2304: Cannot find name 'IDatabaseModel'.
```

- Is it illegal to exoprt an interface by itself in Typescript (citation)?
- How else can I format my code for it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the require syntax I have above needs a default export.

I can change my imports to rather be ES6 like so:

```
import {IDatabaseModel} from './IDatabaseModel';
```

Answer (score 0):

If file contains only type declarations and no actual code it probably should be type declaration file (.d.ts) that can be imported using reference syntax.

IDatabaseModel.d.ts

```
 interface IDatabaseModel {}
```

IDatabaseModels.ts

```
/// <reference path="./IDatabaseModel.d.ts" />
export interface IDatabaseModels {
    currencies : IDatabaseModel;        
}
```

Comment: I would advise against that. `import` doesn't pollute the global space. By making this reference path every module in your app now will have `IDatabaseModel`

Answer (score 0):

It's not illegal to export interfaces in TypeScript.

You already did that in your example.

Although if you want to export interface to be reused in a different application ( compiled separately ). Then you will need to create a specific module for that library and specify a `package.json`'s `typings` property.